# In fancytooltips, how to have a set of aligned equations or matrix

Tags: fancytooltips

The package `fancytooltips` allows for  layers,  where a rollover by mouse over a target brings up a box of comments. I want the target to contain extended mathematical objects such as aligned equations or matrices. To restate, this is somewhat similar to  having a Base and an Exponent. Base is part of the main page and Exponent is the layer that shows up if you hover on Base. I want the Base to be a set of aligned equations or a matrix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tool-tips can contain mathematical expressions. Below there's an example. I used the file following `mathtips.tex` document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[createtips]{fancytooltips}

\colorlet{shadecolor}{blue!20}

\begin{document}

\keytip{distrib}\begin{shaded}
\begin{align}
a ( b + c ) &= ab + ac \\
&= ba + ca \\
&= ( b + c) a
\end{align}
\end{shaded}

\clearpage

\keytip{matrix}\begin{shaded}
\[
I_3 = \begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{shaded}

\end{document}
```

to produce a file `mathtips.pdf` containing the tips (I used the `framed` package to place the tips inside a colored box, but you can style your tips as you wish), and then, using this file `c.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[filename=mathtips,mouseover]{fancytooltips}

\begin{document}

\tooltip{Distributivity}{distrib}

\tooltip{An identity matrix}{matrix}

\end{document}
```

I got the document with the fancy tool-tips; some images:

[image]

and the tool-tips:

[image]

[image]

The `\tooltip{<stuff>}{<keyword>}` command uses an `\hbox` for `<stuff>`, so if you want to use displayed math in `<stuff>` (a set of aligned equations obtained using `amsmath`'s `align` environment, for example), you will need to use the starred version `\tooltip*` (for in-line math material you can still use the non-starred version); consider the following simple example using the same `mathtips.pdf` file as before:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[filename=mathtips,mouseover]{fancytooltips}

\begin{document}

\tooltip{$I_3 = \begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$}{distrib}

\tooltip*{\begin{align}
a ( b + c ) &= ab + ac \\
&= ba + ca \\
&= ( b + c) a
\end{align}}{matrix}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

As a remark, the `noextratext` package option doesn't seem to work when using  displayed mathematical expressions (such as those produced by `align`) in the first argument of `\tooltips*`.

Comment: Thanks, can  we have the BASE, as the item in  \tooltip{BASE}, be a collection of equations or a mtrix. So for example when you mouseover/click on that set of equations or matrix then the additional (exponent) layer shows up. I have been only able to put simple text or simple formula as BASE but not a set of equations with alignment etc.

Comment: @Maesumi Ah, now I see what you meant. The answer is yes; please see my updated answer.

Comment: Great. Except the second base/tooltip* with the \begin{align}  does not seem to work. (The first one with the base the identity matrix works for me as in the picture you posted.)

Comment: @Maesumi: it works for me, as you can see from the image... are you perhaps using outdated packages?

Comment: When I hover on the second formula I do not see any popup. (Also notice that in the text of your program when you hover on matrix  the distributive law is supposed to come up and when you hover on distributive laws the matrix is supposed to show.)

Comment: @Maesumi:Oh, sorry! I posted here an test version which doen't correspond to the images posted; I updated the code (removed the `noextratext` option) and will reupload the right images. Please let me know if things now work for you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3463/discussion-between-maesumi-and-gonzalo-medina)

Comment: @Maesumi: right now I can't, but I'll be here again in approx. 9 hours.